# Extbase property mapping for deleted record

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to build a preview page for a create form. I set "deleted" property of the record to "1" when in `previewAction` because in the BE the list module is used to approve the inserted records - so if the record was never finally saved its deleted anyway.

Problem: I can create the record (`deleted=1`) - I can jump back to the form (no history back for I have to keep the created object). But if I submit again the property mapping tells me

Object of type MyModel with identity "3" not found.

Of course that's because its deleted. The settings in the Repository to ignore deleted are not taking action here.

Yes I could bypass the Extbase magic by filling up everything manually, but this is not what I want.

Here is the action to get an idea what I'm trying

```
 /**
 * action preview
 *
 * @param MyModel
 * @return void
 */
public function previewAction(MyModel $newModel)
{
    //check if model was already saved
    $uid = $this->request->hasArgument('uid') ? this->request->getArgument('uid') : 0;
    if($uid){
        $newModel = $this->myRepository->findDeletedByUid($uid);
        $this->myRepository->update($newModel);
    }
    else{
        $newModel->setDeleted(true);
        $this->myRepository->add($newModel);
    }

    $this->view->assign('ad', $newModel);
    $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

    $uid = $this->persistenceManager->getIdentifierByObject($newModel);
    $this->view->assign('uid', $uid);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Extbase default query settings suppress deleted objects.

Since you've already stated the custom query findDeletedByUid() in your repository, you just need to set it to include deleted records. It is important, however, that if you want to call your controller action using the object, you'll have to retrieve it before calling the action. Use an initialization action for that. The initializaton will be called automatically before the action.

If you want to set wether the object is deleted, you'll also going to need to define a property, getter and setter in your Domain Model and a proper definition in your tca to enable the data mapper to access the column.

In the repository:

```
public function findDeletedByUid($uid) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->getQuerySettings()->setIncludeDeleted(true);
    $query->matching(
        $query->equals('uid',$uid)
    );
    return $query->execute();
}
```

In your Controller class:

```
/**
 * initialize action previewAction
 * Overrides the default initializeAction with one that can retrieve deleted objects
 */
public function initializePreviewAction(){
    if( $this->request->hasArgument('mymodel') ){
      $uid = $this->request->getArgument('mymodel');
      if( $mymodel = $this->mymodelRepository->findDeletedByUid($uid) ){
          $this->request->setArgument($mymodel);
      } else {
          // handle non retrievable object here
      }
    } else {
      // handle missing argument here
    }
}
```

In your Domain Model:

```
...
/**
 * @var bool
 */
protected $deleted;

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function getDeleted() {
    return $this->deleted;
}

/**
 * @param bool $deleted
 */
public function setDeleted($deleted) {
    $this->deleted = $deleted;
}
```

In your tca.php

```
...
'deleted' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.deleted',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'check',
    ),
),
```

Comment: this does not work, because the action param previewAction(MyModel $newModel) is mapped by the property mapper. The property mapper does not use the repository (I think so).

Comment: That' actually a very nice idea - and the model will be updated with the form data? Then this would be the best way of doing it.

Comment: You should then be able to update the object in the repository, yes. If you want to set wether the record is deleted or not, you'll also need a boolean property, getter and setter in your Domain Model. Updated my answer once more.

Comment: Thnx! I will not change my implementation now fpr this project but this is the answer for my question.

Comment: Like it for property mapping of hidden records!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing any magic with deleted, you should use the hidden field to allow editors to preview documents.
You can tell your query to include hidden records inside the repository.

Comment: basically you are right, but its not the behaviour I want to have, that the records are deleted - so they are kind of temporary. Ok whatever I think that's all hacky - so I decided to use a custom flag "saved" to know if the record was approved and finally saved or if the process was never finished. In the backend I have now to tell the admins to take care of this flag or bedder write a backend-module to handle this process - then its clean.

Comment: the property mapper ignores the repository settings - so a hidden object will also be not found - so using the hidden filed has the same effect. Am I wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `findDeletedByUid($uid)` function caught my eye. If it's not a custom function, should it use something like `findByDeleted(TRUE)` or `findByDeleted(1)` in combination with `->getFirst()` or `->findByUid()`? You can find discussions in the [Extbase manual reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#public-repository-api) and the [Repository __call() function API](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_persistence_1_1_repository.html#a6ca24d0cc830839104a34951755a1f27) sections.

Comment: its a custom function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all hints.

I think depending to  the answers its not possible without bypass extbase property-mapping magic. So I think in general its not a good idea to do it like that.

So I put now my own flag "stored" to the model.

In BE List-Module the not "stored" objects are still visible, but using an own BE Module or deleting the not "stored" object by a cron-job should do the job.

If anyone has a bedder idea feel free to share it :-)

Comment: We did. You don't need a separate flag for this functionality. Just determine if you want the objects to remain in the backend, and use deleted or hidden based on that. Then modify your repository accordingly.